# Git: Overwriting Multiple Commits on Remote Feature Branch after Local Rebase/Squash

Tags: git, github

- I forked a GitHub repo at **otherusername/X** to my own account at **myusername/X**
- I have been developing locally and pushing commits up to **myusername/X** on branch **myfeature**, and have submitted a pull request to merge **myusername/X myfeature** into **otherusername/X master**
- Over the course of development and receiving feedback on my open pull request, I have made 10 commits to **myfeature**. Now development is done and we are ready to merge, so I squash my commits locally with `git rebase -i origin/master` down to a single commit.
- Now the **myfeature** branch at **myusername/X** has the 10 commits that I pushed up, and my local **myfeature** has just a single commit
- When I try to `git push` **myfeature**, so that **myusername/X myfeature** will have a single commit and can be cleanly merged to **otherusername/X master**, git complains that my local branch is behind the remote branch, and that I need to pull the changes from the remote branch. But this would recreate all those commits I just squashed.

#### How do I update the **myusername/X myfeature** branch to have only a single commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking to force push. e.g. `git push -f remote myfeature`

What is happening is that when you rebased locally and squashed commits, you diverged from the remote branch's history. (e.g. you rewrote history). Being a focused feature branch, that you're the only developer on, force push is probably ok in this case, however heed the many warnings you will find around about rewriting history and force pushing, as you can easily cause bad things to happen.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I could imagine is as follows:

You keep your local **myfeature**, delete the remote branch and recreate it with your single commit on your local **myfeature**

```
git push remote :myfeature
git push remote myfeature

remote in this case is your myusername/X
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid to try this though for fear that it would somehow mess up the pull request if I deleted the remote branch that it used.

Comment: @sean which pull again? Sure if you try to pull from a delted remote banch you will get a `remote end hung up unexpectedly` but why would you pull in the first place??

Comment: What I meant is that the remote **myfeature** branch is already on one end of a pull request between **myusername/X** and **otherusername/X**. If I delete this branch, even if I immediately recreate it by pushing up a new one (with the single commit), will I have to recreate the pull request with the new branch, thereby losing the comments/etc from the old PR?